# How to pass value from HTML to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I built my website with node.js and I want to show blog posts on homepage. I have already built blog posts section on homepage. It shows latest news from MySQL database. When users click on a picture in index site, it will redirect users to content site.

Assume that the latest news ID is 16. In the code below, it will redirect users to news #16 site. How can I change number 16 to something more general? (pass <%=news_data[0].news_id%> value to showNews function)

**main.js**

```
app.get('/', querydataIndex)
app.get('/news-16', showNews)

function querydataIndex(req,res){
    var sql_news = 'select * from news order by news_id desc limit 3'
    var sql_training = 'select * from trainingcourse order by course_id desc limit 3'
    server.query(sql_news+';'+sql_training,[1,2],function(error,data){
        res.render('pages/index',{news_data: data[0],training_data: data[1]})
    })
}

function showNews(req,res){
    var sql = 'select * from news where news_id='+'16'+' order by news_id desc'
    data=[]
    server.query(sql,data,function(error,data){
        res.render('pages/news-content',{data: data})
    })
}
```

**index.ejs**

```
<div class="col-md-4 ">
   <div class="card">
      <a href="news-<%=news_data[0].news_id%>"><img class="card-img-top" src="img/news/<%=news_data[0].news_id%>.jpg"></a>
      <div class="card-body contentIndex">
         <h5 class="card-title"><%=news_data[0].topic%></h5>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**news-content.ejs**

```
<h2 class="card-title"><%=data[0].topic%></h2>
<h5 class="card-text"><%=data[0].content%></h5>
```

Comment: See [Express route parameters](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters)

Comment: Use more cleaner format-  `app.get('/news/16', showNews)` instead of  `app.get('/news-16', showNews)`

Answer (score 0):

Simply make a variable which is a string and set it equal to "news-"+{{ID}} which you get from calling your db